# Android Open Source project .disconnect method & BluetoothHeadsetClient class is hide any solution

Tags: bluetooth, android-source, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

```
public void disconnect(final BluetoothDevice device) {
    if (mClient != null) {
        mClient.disconnect(device);
    }
}
```

.disconnect() method is @hide by AOSP. I have tried to access BluetoothHeadsetClient class & BluetoothProfile and BluetoothDevice class.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple explanation for this. It is a pretty sure sign that the architect of this function does not want it to be used in applications.

If it is necessary from an application point of view, there is probably also an official way to use this function via another interface.

For example, the [Bluetooth Headset class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset)  gives you access to information and functions related to this device.